# How do I find if a Hive table is defined as an external table through PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

For context - data lives on S3, written as Hive tables. I'm running some Jupyter notebooks on my local machine that's supposed to point to the S3 data as Hive tables, with the metdata being stored on some relational DB on a Spark cluster.

When I run some local scripts/Jupyter notebooks on my local machine to create and load some tables, it's saying that I've created some external tables even though I didn't create them as external tables.

When I run `spark.sql("show tables in target_db").show(20, False)` I see nothing. Then I create the table without the `external` option, then run the show command again, which outputs :

```
+----------+-------------------+-----------+
|database  |tableName          |isTemporary|
+----------+-------------------+-----------+
|target_db |mytable            |false      |
+----------+-------------------+-----------+
```

and run my script, which errors out, saying ``` : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Operation not allowed: TRUNCATE TABLE on external tables: ``target_db``.``mytable``; ```

I dropped the table on the cluster itself, so I think there's no issue with that. How is Spark thinking that my table is an external table? Do I need to change how I'm creating the table?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should access the data from s3 by creating external table. Say this table is called T1.
2. If the table T1 definition uses partitions then you need to repair the table to load the partitions.
3. You cannot truncate external table T1. You should only read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Tables created with `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ...` statement are external.
Tables created with `CREATE TABLE` are not.

You can check which one with a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`
or with a `DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name`, the field called `Type` can be `MANAGED` or `EXTERNAL`.